# Showing a .mdl file

Tags: node.js

I was wondering if there is anyway of showing a .mdl file withing a Node.JS application.

If not if there are any other solutions for it, for example maybe taking a picture of the model with Node.JS somehow and exporting it to some sort of an image file.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: What is a .mdl file?

Comment: a model file, for example Source Engine models.

Just some sort of a model file to be able to be presented on the site.

Comment: There a few third party services offering a 3d viewer: https://a360.autodesk.com/viewer http://p3d.in/ http://www.3dvieweronline.com/ http://www.investintech.com/resources/blog/archives/2702-4-cool-ways-to-view-3d-content-in-your-browser.html You can also do it by yourself but no MDL support (if you can convert to a compatible format, it's fine): http://doc.x3dom.org/tutorials/models/thirdParty/index.html https://github.com/humu2009/jsc3d/tree/master/jsc3d https://github.com/tbuser/thingiview.js